# Multiple @POST tags in a class

Tags: java, rest, post

Is it possible to have multiple @POST tags in a class/interface. Let me know if this code is problematic, and if so why:

```
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/user/raflets/{appId}/admin/batch/{batchId}/instance")
public interface RafletJobInstanceRestService {

@GET
@Path("/{instanceId}")
JobInstanceBean getJobInstanceDetails(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        @PathParam("appId") int appId, @PathParam("batchId") int batchId,
        @PathParam("instanceId") int instanceId);

@POST
@Path("/{instanceId}")
JobInstanceBean updateInstance(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        @PathParam("appId") int appId, @PathParam("batchId") int batchId,
        @PathParam("instanceId") int instanceId,
        JobInstanceBean batchInstance);

@POST
@Path("/clone/{instanceId}")
JobInstanceBean cloneInstance(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        @PathParam("appId") int appId, @PathParam("batchId") int batchId,
        @PathParam("instanceId") int instanceId,
        JobInstanceBean batchInstance);
}
```

I figured since each post call has a different path there wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Yes, there won't be a problem, except that it won't be restful. You can use this code as is.

Comment: @11thdimension I'm wondering why do you say: it won't be RESTful

Comment: `@POST` is supposed to put an entry in the collection, so two POSTs violate that rule. It will still be perfectly fine with the utilization point of view, but it won't be restful. Check this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: I get it...but still I don't see why it's not RESTful since is not the same POST over the same URI, so separating it into another file and having two POSTs is roughly the same (is SoC is your issue)

Comment: @11thdimension is absolutely right. The REST architecture is very strict as far as services like this being limited to the typical CRUD operations on a specific element using HTTP verbs: GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. Having said that, it's up to you how strictly you want to adhere to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to have multiple `@POST` annotations. And fine to have multiple `@GET` annotations for that matter. They just specify the HTTP verb that an API endpoint should respond to.

On a related note, if your API is served over HTTPS and you're sending sensitive data in these POST requests, you may want to consider sending that data as POST parameters in the header instead of in the URL. The API endpoint and parameters in the URL will still be visible, but your sensitive data would be encrypted in the header. In order to do this, you would just remove them from the path in your service and retrieve them using `@FormParam` instead of `@PathParam`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'd upvote ya, but i dont have the rep haha.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.